# Fetch request not returning any data in console, or on front end

Tags: javascript, fetch

When I submit my form, I am not returning any data, not even in my console. I am trying to return details from WHOIS regarding the URL that is searched, and am getting nothing back.

Can anyone provide any advice as to why this might be the case?

Here is my front end script tag, after my form:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); getDetails(); })
async function getDetails(url = `http://localhost:3000/lookup/${url}`, data = {}) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(async response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then(json => resolve(json))
          console.log(data);
        } else {
          response.json().then(json => reject(json))
        }
      }).catch(async error => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

On my express backend I am using `req.params.url` if that helps provide any context at all...

My Status Code is 200, and all appears to be normal in the Headers tab...

Comment: Are you running `getDetails.then()`? Get details returns a promise, so you'll need to execute the promise

Comment: @Sam right... I knew that haha

Comment: If you're not using `await` inside your function, it should not be labeled `async`. Alternatively you can refactor that function so it doesn't use promises (instead use `await`)

Comment: @Derek How would I do so>

Comment: Here's an example of a basic async function: `async function xyz(url) { try { const response = await fetch(url); return response.json(); } catch (e) { console.log(error); } };`

Comment: @Derek So in the case of this example, would I just put await before ```fetch```?

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for further instruction on how to use async/await

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix of promise and async syntax, which is confusing, let's translate it first by unpicking the `promise` and `then` into `await` (if you can use `async` then do, it's easer than `Promise`/`then`):

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener(
    'submit', 
    function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        getDetails(); 
    });

async function getDetails(url = `http://localhost:3000/lookup/${url}`, data = {}) 
{
    // Fetch will throw an exception if it can't connect to the service
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    if (response.ok)
        return await response.json();
    
    // We could connect but got an error back from the service
    // There may not be a response body, so response.json() or .body() might crash
    throw new Error(`Error from server ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`;
    
    // We don't need catch, as any exception in an await will cascade up anyway
}
```

This makes it much more readable, and it's apparent that `getDetails` doesn't make any changes itself, it just returns the JSON from the service. The fix needs to be in the event listener - it needs to *do* something with that result:

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener(
    'submit', 
    async e => { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        const searchResult = await getDetails();

        // Do something to show the results, populate #results
        const resultsElement = document.getElementById('results');
        resultsElement.innerText = JSON.stringify(searchResult);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-using `async`/`await`.  Try this:

```
async function getDetails(url = `http://localhost:3000/lookup/${url}`, data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  if (response.ok) {
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  } else {
     throw new Error(json);
  }
}
```

In essence `await` is a replacement for `then` (but you can only use it in functions marked with `async`).

Comment: there is no `resolve` function in this context, instead you just want to `return json;`

Comment: Fixed it to return instead.